# Original exception text was: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'name' using django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm learning Django and i got to this error and I couldn't find the solution.

Here are my **models**

```
class Retailer(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    website = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)

class Product(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    price = models.IntegerField(default=None, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    retailer = models.ForeignKey(Retailer,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='retailer_info')
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

And here are my **serializers**

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = '__all__'

class RetailerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    products = ProductSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Retailer
        fields = ['name', 'website', 'products']
```

And here's my **view**

```
class RetailerList(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        retailer = Retailer.objects.all()
        serializer = RetailerSerializer(retailer)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

And here's my **url**

```
path('retailer', views.RetailerList.as_view()),
```

But when I submit a get request on *127.0.0.1:8000/retailer* i get this error:

> AttributeError at /product
>   Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `name` on serializer `RetailerSerializer`.
>   The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `QuerySet` instance.
>   Original exception text was: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'name'.
>   What's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add `many=True` in the `RetailerSerializer`, since you are *not* serializing a single element, but a list of elements. Furthermore you should for example return this as a`JsonResponse`:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

class RetailerList(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        retailer = Retailer.objects.all()
        serializer = RetailerSerializer(retailer, many=True)
        return JsonResponse({'data': serializer.data})
```

Comment: Error fixed thanks a lot. Sorry for that I am taking your time, how can I take each retailer products in response?

Comment: @ValaKhosravi: since the `related_name` is `retailer_info`, it should be `retaler_info` in the `fields` of the `Meta`, and in the field of your serializer. But you likely misunderstood `related_name`: `related_name` is the name of the relation in *reverse*, so likely you want to change `related_name` in the `ForeignKey` to `'products'`.

Comment: thanks a lot again. I really don't know where to find good tutorials for Django rest framework.